# Alert breaks code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I am looking to create an alert at the end with the calculation of foodCaught and foodWasted, for some reason my alert seems to break every time that it is incorporated into the script. Also how do I create a visual timer for that once it is up my the alert runs and outputs the foodCaught and foodWasted values? Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cnv = $("#myCanvas")[0];
    var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
    var catcherX = ctx.canvas.width/2;
    var catcherY = ctx.canvas.height - 100; // set the initial location of the catcher's y position
    var numFoods = 5;
    var catcherSpeed = 30;
    var foodCaught = 0;
    var foodWasted = 0;

    function Food(){ // the name of the constructor usually begins with a captial letter
        this.radius = 30;

        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width);
        this.y = 0 - this.radius;
        this.speed = 1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
        var imageToUse = new Image();
        this.width = 50; // default values
        this.height = 50; // default values

        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*2); // create a random number to choose the image
        if(randomNum == 0){

            imageToUse.src = "corn.png";
            this.width = 27; // width of corn.png
            this.height = 100; // height of corn.png

        } else if(randomNum == 1){
           imageToUse.src = "straw.png"
            this.width = 83; // width of straw.png
            this.height = 100; // height of straw.png
        }  

        this.moveFood = function(){
            if(this.y > ctx.canvas.height){
                this.x =  Math.floor(Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width);
                this.y = 0;
                footWasted += 1;
            }         
            this.y += this.speed; // add speed to location
        }

        this.drawFood = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageToUse, this.x, this.y);
        }

        this.intersectFood = function(targetX, targetY, targetR) {

            if(this.x + this.width > targetX && this.x < targetX + targetR && this.y + this.height > targetY && this.y < targetY + targetR){
              foodCaught += 1;
               return true;
            }
            /*

            var distanceX = this.x - targetX;
            var distanceY = this.y - targetY;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

            if(distance < targetR + this.radius){
                return true;
             }
             */

        }

    } //Food function

    // create an Array of Foods
    var FoodArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<numFoods; i++) {
        FoodArray[i] = new Food();
    }

    // get mouse Postion
    $(document).keydown(function(e){ // attach the event to the entire document
        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 37:    // left
                catcherX-= catcherSpeed;
                break;
            case 39:    // right
                catcherX+= catcherSpeed;
                break;
        }
    });


    setInterval(gameLoop,10); // call draw every 10 milliseconds

    function gameLoop(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); //clears previous circles
        for(var i=0; i < FoodArray.length; i++) {
            FoodArray[i].moveFood();
            FoodArray[i].drawFood();
            if(FoodArray[i].intersectFood(catcherX, catcherY, 15)){
                FoodArray.splice(i,1);
                 console.log(i);
            }
        }

        // draw catcher
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle="#119933";
        ctx.arc(catcherX,catcherY,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by alert? Like `window.alert()`? How does it break everything? There's no alert in the code you provided.

Comment: What do you mean by 'break code'?

Comment: And when do you want this alert to pop up? Every 10ms in the game loop?

Comment: But do you have any error message or something like that from the browser console?

Comment: Any errors? Have you checked the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the game to last 1 minute, and the alert to fire at the end of the game, it should look something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cnv = $("#myCanvas")[0];
    var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
    var catcherX = ctx.canvas.width/2;
    var catcherY = ctx.canvas.height - 100; // set the initial location of the catcher's y position
    var numFoods = 5;
    var catcherSpeed = 30;
    var foodCaught = 0;
    var foodWasted = 0;
    var gameInProgress = true; //game state

    function Food(){ // the name of the constructor usually begins with a captial letter
        this.radius = 30;

        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width);
        this.y = 0 - this.radius;
        this.speed = 1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
        var imageToUse = new Image();
        this.width = 50; // default values
        this.height = 50; // default values

        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*2); // create a random number to choose the image
        if(randomNum == 0){

            imageToUse.src = "corn.png";
            this.width = 27; // width of corn.png
            this.height = 100; // height of corn.png

        } else if(randomNum == 1){
           imageToUse.src = "straw.png"
            this.width = 83; // width of straw.png
            this.height = 100; // height of straw.png
        }  

        this.moveFood = function(){
            if(this.y > ctx.canvas.height){
                this.x =  Math.floor(Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width);
                this.y = 0;
                footWasted += 1;
            }         
            this.y += this.speed; // add speed to location
        }

        this.drawFood = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imageToUse, this.x, this.y);
        }

        this.intersectFood = function(targetX, targetY, targetR) {

            if(this.x + this.width > targetX && this.x < targetX + targetR && this.y + this.height > targetY && this.y < targetY + targetR){
              foodCaught += 1;
               return true;
            }
            /*

            var distanceX = this.x - targetX;
            var distanceY = this.y - targetY;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

            if(distance < targetR + this.radius){
                return true;
             }
             */

        }

    } //Food function

    // create an Array of Foods
    var FoodArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<numFoods; i++) {
        FoodArray[i] = new Food();
    }

    // get mouse Postion
    $(document).keydown(function(e){ // attach the event to the entire document
        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 37:    // left
                catcherX-= catcherSpeed;
                break;
            case 39:    // right
                catcherX+= catcherSpeed;
                break;
        }
    });


    var gameInterval = setInterval(gameLoop,10); // call draw every 10 milliseconds

    function gameLoop(){
        if(!gameInProgress)
            clearInterval(gameInterval); //end game
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); //clears previous circles
        for(var i=0; i < FoodArray.length; i++) {
            FoodArray[i].moveFood();
            FoodArray[i].drawFood();
            if(FoodArray[i].intersectFood(catcherX, catcherY, 15)){
                FoodArray.splice(i,1);
                 console.log(i);
            }
        }

        // draw catcher
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle="#119933";
        ctx.arc(catcherX,catcherY,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

    }

    setTimeout(endGame, 60*1000); //end game after 1 minute

    function endGame(){
        gameInProgress = false;
        alert("Food caught: "+foodCaught+"\nFood wasted: "+foodWasted);
    }
});
```

If you want to show a timer for the game you should do it like this:

```js
function timer(time){  //timer definition
  var timeLeft = time;
  var timerInterval = undefined;
  var updateFunction = undefined;
  
  var decrement = function(){ //function that decreses timeLeft value, calls update function and checks if it's over
    timeLeft--;
    updateFunction(timeLeft);
    if(timeLeft == 0)
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
  }
  
  return {  //object returned for the caller to use
    start: function(updateFunc){  //start function, that takes update function as a parameter
      updateFunction = updateFunc;
      updateFunction(timeLeft); //update the value with initial timeLeft value
      timerInterval = setInterval(decrement, 1000);  //interval that decreses timeLeft by one every second
    }
  }
}

//document.ready
$(function(){
  timer(10).start(function(time){
      $("#timer").text(time);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this worked perfectly!!! Now I am also wondering if you know, how to make the timer a visible timer?

Comment: Where would you like timer to be shown. Inside canvas or outside (say in some div or span?)

Comment: Outside the canvas in a div!

Comment: I've added a timer definition inside my answer. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for all the questions I really do appreciate all your answers you are really helping me. So how exactly do I attach this timer to the function that spits our the data results that you gave me earlier?

Comment: Like how exactly to I implement that into the code I already have? With the result:

Comment: function endGame(){
        gameInProgress = false;
        alert("Food caught: "+foodCaught+"\nFood wasted: "+foodWasted);
    }

Comment: You can just put the timer code (`function timer(time){ ... }`) above your `$(document).ready(...)` function, and than at the end of `$(document).ready` function you can call it, like I did inside `$(function(){ ... });` block - just change 10 seconds to 60 seconds and change ID of the div you want to show timer in.